# Keep table at a set width and have overflow in mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am struggling to keep a table within a table to stay at a set width and in mobile to have a horizontal scroll.

That way nothing gets squished and i can maintain readability. I am attempting to use pure *CSS* before resorting to *javascript/jQuery.*

Current example:

**(LINK HAS BEEN REMOVED)**

The DOM structure i currently have:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Vessel name and $</td>
        <td>
            <div class="container">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Sold</td>
                        <td>Sold</td>
                        <td>Available</td>
                        <td>Sold</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>Proceed button</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The table in the `container` i want to keep at a set width e.g 500px and when we go into mobile i'd like to be able to have a horizontal overflow so users can swipe/scroll through the availability for that particular vessel.

I have a development page which illustrates what i'd like to achieve, it also contains CSS that i've used so far (note, still tinkering).

**(LINK HAS BEEN REMEOVED)**

Comment: I'm assuming `max-width` is out of the question?

Comment: @rybo111 I haven't exhausted the use of max-width. If you look at the dev site now and do a hard refresh i've made some headway now. I do have some horizontal scrolling happening now!

Answer (score 1):

A possibility would be media queries, to make the div scrollable on small resolutions.

```
@media(max-width: 767px) {
  .container {
    overflow-x: scroll;
  }
}
```